# InstallShield Installer is Creating Duplicate Programs in Control Panel

Tags: .net, installation, installshield-le

I have an installer that I created using InstallShield Limited. After installing, I noticed something weird happening. I have multiple entries of the application in my Control Panel.

My steps I take when I update the version:
1. Update application files.
2. Go to General Information, and create a new Product Code (Do not change the Upgrade Code).

[image]

UPDATE:

I found out that it occurs when I include .NET 4.5 as a Redistributable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this happens because you forgot to increase the Product Version. Change the Product Version to a higher version and this should help you upgrade/remove the older version.